# Set width of div to the right of a fixed sidebar to be the remaining 100% of viewport

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Notice how I have to add the width: calc(100% - 50px); style to both #header-wrapper and #footer-wrapper. This is to account for the fixed sidebar that is 50px wide.

I am trying to figure out why I can't just add the style width: calc(100% - 50px); to #main-wrapper instead of both #header-wrapper and #footer.

**To reproduce do the following with the code snippet:**
Change width to 100% in both #header-wrapper and #footer. Add width calc(100% - 50px); to #main-wrapper. Notice footer gets cutoff.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#main-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: 100px;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #777;
}

#subheader {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#subheader h4 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15.4px;
    margin-bottom: 15.4px;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    height: calc(100% - 130px);
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: 30px;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#footer .text-muted {
    color: #bdbdbd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
                My Site Title
            </div>
            <div id="subheader" class="container-fluid">
                <h4>Page title</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="pull-right">
        <p>Footer content that gets cut off</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case you can just use the below code :

*note : you should not set the main content of your html page position fixed, then you can set margin-top for it, 
in the other parts the calc function is removed and still the page layout is good ! :)

```css
* * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:2;
}

#main-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left : 0;
    top : 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #777;
}

#subheader {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#subheader h4 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15.4px;
    margin-bottom: 15.4px;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top : 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index:2;
    background : #fff;
}

#footer .text-muted {
    color: #bdbdbd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
                My Site Title
            </div>
            <div id="subheader" class="container-fluid">
                <h4>Page title</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="pull-right">
        <p>Footer content that gets cut off</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think your getting somewhere, however notice that something is wrong with the container-fluid of header and subheader. The padding isn't showing when inspecting element like it is in the footer. Very strange that footer is working in your example, but those aren't.

Comment: Right click the header and inspect element. Look to the right side, you will see the container-fluid padding is missing. Add a <div class="pull-right">This text will get cut off in header</div> to the #header div.

Comment: When you say not to set the main content of my html page to fixed. Do you mean the sidebar and main-wrapper divs which are the two outer elements? I thought these needed to be fixed to ensure they can always be viewed by the user. Especially when the content scrolls.

Comment: now check it, the layout is fixed, but the #content container has bugs that I'm working on fixing it

Comment: Looks like you did it! Can you please adjust the layout to be how you would recommend. If I can avoid using fixed and still achieve the same goal that would be awesome. The key pieces are to have the sidebar, header, subheader, footer always be viewed by the user and the content scrollable. As you can see I really don't want to use bootstrap unless it is for elements inside of one of my layout divs.

Comment: I guess I have a misunderstanding of when I should be using fixed, relative, or absolute in this layout..

Comment: with this solution you can do what you actually need, for more samples for creating layouts, you can check the admin panel html themes with the side bar menu, they can help you to improve techniques, side nav and top nav are always fixed, but not position: fixed, you must just use position : fixed for outer containers, now the layout architecture is correct, then you need to set some parts scrollable

Comment: bottom scroll arrow of content is missing.

Comment: it looks like that did it! Can you fill me on on the key changes you made from my original. It looks like the biggest one was making main-wrapper relative. I noticed you are setting all elements to border-box could this cause any issues in the future? I am aware this is what bootstrap uses.

Comment: yes, i made header and footer wrappers absolute, and at the end, the content wrapper relative, i think we must prevent discussions here, if you have more questions, we should go to discussion section, is there any thing that i can help you with ?

Comment: if we can go to discussion for a few mins that would be great!

Comment: Just need the link to popup to move to chat.

Comment: so you can close this question, then i can answer your other questions

Comment: Closed, but still don't know why the move discussion to chat link isn't showing. The thread is already long enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150005/discussion-between-arash-khajelou-and-blake-rivell).

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because your elements are positioned as "fixed" and therefore are taken out of the document flow. In addition, they are positioned relative to the viewport (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning).

A different approach in styling these two elements could be the following:

```
#header-wrapper,
#footer {
    width: auto; // Drop the width declaration or set it to auto
    left: 50px;  // And position it with "left" and "right" 
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I am wondering why I can't do the calculation or left:50px on the main-wrapper which is an element on the same level as the sidebar. How come it has to be added to the individual elements (header-wrapper and footer) that are inside the main-wrapper?

Comment: Because the have `position: fixed`, so they don't respect the boundaries of your main-wrapper

Comment: so your saying my current code or changing it to what your telling me is as clean as its going to get due to position: fixed? I believe your code is an alternative solution to what I already have. It is just replacing calc and making it more browser friendly correct?

Comment: I guess you can say that. As far as I know, there is no real other way instead of calc or left/right

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking after?
I calculated the width by taking 100vw - the 50px of the red bar.

The reason why it got cut off is because if the width is 100%, it's 100% width of the wrapping  element. Because you used position:fixed and it actually extended beyond what you could see.

Since the text would have to align to the right side of the avaialbe room, it went into the "invisible part" and drawed itself from that offset.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
    padding:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}

#main-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    float: left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color: #777;
}

#subheader {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin:0px;
}

#subheader h4 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top:15.4px;    
}

#content {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin:0px;
    /**          viewport-header-footer-unknown **/
    height: calc(100vh - 100px - 30px - 21px );
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#footer .text-muted {
    color: #bdbdbd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
                My Site Title
            </div>
            <div id="subheader" class="container-fluid">
                <h4>Page title</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tincidunt maximus tristique. In id sapien imperdiet, auctor
                tortor quis, ultrices justo. Integer nisi arcu, accumsan nec laoreet non, efficitur a mi. Integer ultricies
                leo non rutrum posuere. Vestibulum mattis sollicitudin rhoncus. Nullam elementum lacus velit, eu consequat
                dolor suscipit a. Sed nec varius risus, quis eleifend nunc. Nullam hendrerit tellus a sem malesuada luctus.
                Proin ornare mi nec nulla tristique, iaculis gravida ipsum fermentum. Sed eget massa sed erat mattis maximus
                eget in sem. Donec imperdiet dictum cursus. Duis vel magna volutpat, ornare quam lobortis, pellentesque sem.
                Sed arcu risus, pretium vel mauris eu, porta faucibus enim. Sed nec nibh est. Suspendisse volutpat ac risus
                quis rhoncus. Pellentesque sed semper neque. Nam id risus tristique, viverra mauris vitae, eleifend enim.
                Donec suscipit luctus odio, sed bibendum sem viverra id. Donec fringilla feugiat felis, quis imperdiet nisl
                egestas eget. Nam lacinia ligula quis quam cursus, quis fermentum mauris aliquam. Donec blandit orci id mauris
                condimentum tempus. Phasellus molestie odio felis, nec feugiat lacus bibendum eget. Vivamus molestie pellentesque
                lacinia. Nam est leo, efficitur ac risus ac, placerat commodo nisi. Aenean non tincidunt massa. In sollicitudin
                ultrices risus at ornare. Ut et lacus massa. Fusce et ultricies odio. Nullam mattis risus quis sapien iaculis,
                in consequat libero congue. Donec feugiat volutpat velit sed porttitor. Mauris dui mi, ullamcorper non porta
                vel, consectetur eget quam. Mauris dolor quam, vulputate interdum auctor eget, tincidunt id enim. Vivamus
                aliquam consectetur magna. Morbi porta tortor ex, quis varius ex tincidunt non. Proin dapibus non lacus eget
                vestibulum. Morbi efficitur nulla in turpis venenatis, eget ornare mauris tristique. Pellentesque auctor
                fringilla rhoncus. Donec auctor in neque non rhoncus. Nunc consequat, ipsum a hendrerit aliquet, odio tortor
                bibendum nunc, quis feugiat purus purus et libero. Nulla leo nisi, laoreet nec vulputate accumsan, lobortis
                nec sapien. Donec blandit purus ut tempor hendrerit. Phasellus sed massa velit. Integer fringilla at arcu
                ac venenatis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas sit amet varius enim.
                Curabitur quis sagittis dolor. Phasellus scelerisque leo ante, ac bibendum ante placerat in. Aenean volutpat
                tempus massa vel mollis. Quisque et lacus ac augue tincidunt eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                adipiscing elit. Duis blandit arcu sed ligula maximus, ac commodo sapien lobortis. Pellentesque hendrerit
                mauris nibh, a semper libero maximus in. Suspendisse non arcu leo. Aliquam eget orci id elit consectetur
                maximus ac vitae lacus. Nam tristique elit ac urna tempor, quis convallis mauris lobortis. Nulla dictum lorem
                ac dolor rhoncus blandit eget vitae neque. Nunc quis elit sit amet sem iaculis vestibulum. Proin viverra
                orci non nulla tempus congue. Nam vitae faucibus massa. Nullam vulputate dolor sit amet luctus molestie.
                Nunc mattis blandit ligula eu tincidunt. Pellentesque sit amet magna a tellus molestie fringilla sed placerat
                tortor.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="pull-right">
        <p>Footer content that gets cut off</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out why width can't just be calculated on the outer main-wrapper.. why does it have to be done on the divs within it?

Comment: if you look at my example, I only set the width calculation on the footer, the other ones I set to 100%.

Comment: yes, I see but the footer is inside main-wrapper why should it need a width calc if main-wrapper gets a width calc?

Comment: You used position fixed. That is as if you added it directly to the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Tschallacka I should have known that. Thank you for clearing that up. I wonder if there is anyway to setup this same exact layout where I am not using position: fixed on those inner elements and still have it stay fixed above the scrollable content.

Comment: You really don't need the fixed elements. You just need to add a `overflow-y: scroll` to your content div. and a height of 100vw - menu height - title height - footer height;

Comment: Are you serious? Any chance you can update your snippet to do that. If not no big deal, I will attempt it. Are you sure not a single element needs to be fixed to achieve this layout? I added overflow-y: scroll and height: calc(100vw - 50px - 50px - 30px); to content div. I believe there is a lot more to it when removing fixed from everything else.

Comment: it looks like you achieved exactly what I wanted. Can you note some of the key changes you made to do this? I still see a lot of elements are fixed.

Comment: use `display:inline-block` to make elements float to left or right whilst being able to set width and height. then float them to the left the bar and main wrapper. Then in main elements make things 100% so they'll sort under eachother, set margin to 0 to get rid of empty spaces in between, and work with known heights. Only thing I can't figure out where the random 21 pixels come from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150004/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-tschallacka).